# Maven RPM Plugin fails to find rpm command in intellij

Tags: maven-2, intellij-idea

I have a module I am trying to package as an RPM using Maven RPM plugin.  When I run mvn package from the command line, it generates the rpm as expected.  When I try to run the package phase from within Intellij, it seems unable to find the rpm command:

```
[WARNING] /bin/sh: rpm: command not found
```

...followed later by:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:rpm-maven-plugin:2.1-alpha-1:rpm (default-rpm) on project ve_hive_client: RPM query for default vendor returned: '127' executing '/bin/sh -c rpm -E '%{_host_vendor}'' -> [Help 1]
```

My hunch is that my rpm installation (/usr/local/bin/rpm) isn't available in Intellij's PATH.  Any idea how to add it?

Comment: Which operating system?  Is this on Linux or are you trying to assemble RPMs on Mac OS X?

Answer (score 4):

had the same problem on ubuntu. i just installed the rpm program and the PATH then had rpm then.

/usr/bin/rpm

Maven did not complain then

Answer (score 0):

try adding:

```
PATH=PATH:/usr/local/bin/rpm
```

in your .bashrc?

Not sure if this will help or not, but worth a try.

Comment: That path does not exist on my Mac (with macports already installed).

Answer (score 0):

If you are running OSX and you've installed rpm using homebrew then it's not related with paths or rpm itself.

In OSX executing

```
/bin/sh -c rpm -E '%{_host_vendor}'
```

is different than executing

```
/bin/sh -c "rpm -E '%{_host_vendor}'"
```

The latter works pretty well.

Anyone found a way to fix this without changing the plug-in's source code?

Comment: i fixed it by linking /usr/local/bin/rpm and /usr/local/bin/rpmbuild to /bin

like ln -s /usr/local/bin/rpm /bin/rpm